# regex for multiple option

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regex expression to use with JS .match() function. The objective is to check a string with multiple alternatives. For example, I want to return true in below code if mystr contains word1 or word2 or word3

```
mystr1 = "this_is_my_test string_containing_word2_where_i_will_perform_search";
mystr2 = "this_is_my_test string_where_i_will_perform_search";
myregex = xxxxxx; // I want help regarding this line so that 
if(mystr1.match(myregex)) return true; //should return true
if(mystr2.match(myregex)) return true; //should NOT return true
```

Any help please?

Comment: The regex would check if the str contains any of the options: word1, word2 or word3?

Comment: yes, that is my intention ... but all words will be in a string in comma separated format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So use the OR `|` in your RegEx:

```
myregex = /word1|word2|word3/;
```

Comment: So, if my words are in a variable (comma separated), should this work?
s = $var.replace(",","|");
myregex = new RegExp(s,"i");

Answer (score 2):

The regex is: `/word1|word2|word3/`

Be aware that, as well as your code would work, you are actually not using the method you need.

- `string.match(regex)` -> returns an array of matches. When evaluated as boolean, it would return `false` when empty (that's why it works).
- `regex.test(string)` -> is what you should use. It evaluates if the string matches the regex and return a `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not making use of your matches then I might be inclined to using the `test()` method and including the `i` flag as well.

```
if( /word1|word2|word3/i.test( mystr1 ) ) return true; //should return true
if( /word1|word2|word3/i.test( mystr2 ) ) return true; //should NOT return true
```